# Async event handler - flycapture from PointGrey

Tags: vb.net, async-await, flycapture

I am using Point Grey's FlyCapture API to drive some cameras.
In a public class, I implemented all the starting and initializing code ; in the following _cam refers to a ManagedGigECamera.
Because I have 16 cameras, I want the code to be as fast as possible, so I wanted to use tasks.

Here is the code I use:

```
    _cam.StartCapture(AddressOf OnImageGrabbed)

.../...

     Public Sub OnImageGrabbed(ByVal raw_image As ManagedImage)
                Dim t As Task = Task.Run(Sub() 
                                     'save image to disk or whatever
                                         End Sub)
                t.Wait()
     End Sub
```

The above gives -sort of- satisfaction. By viewing image timestamps, I can see that some images are saved seconds after they are grabbed, and even some images are skipped altogether...
I wanted to make sure each call to OnImageGrabbed would start a new task, and tried the following, but it crashes right away with 'object not set to an instance of an object' (can't really debug, the code is running on a remote machine)

```
    _cam.StartCapture(AddressOf OnImageGrabbed)

.../...

     Public Async Sub OnImageGrabbed(ByVal raw_image As ManagedImage)
                Await Task.Run(Sub() 
                                     'save image to disk or whatever
                                         End Sub)
     End Sub
```

All in all, my questions are:

- how can I run an event handler asynchronously ?
- why, using the first code, do I get (what appears to be) random delays between each call
  to OnImageGrabbed ? I mean the differences in time between image timestamps is never the same, and tend to increase on the long run (first few images are almost synchronized, but after 1 minute or so, each image is separated by more and more time). Memory leak ? GC ?

Thanks in advance for any hint !

EDIT:
In the end I changed the way the system works: I fire a software trigger on each camera using a timer, and each trigger is fired 'in parallel':

```
Parallel.ForEach(Of ListOfCameras)(SingleCamera, 
      Sub(aCamera, loopstate, num)
            aCamera.FireTrigger()
      End Sub)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a task and then immediately blocking on it (via `Wait`) nets you nothing. You may as well just run the saving-image code directly.

The second example is actually asynchronous. You're probably getting an exception because the `ManagedImage` argument or one of its child objects is being disposed. Remember that the code raising the event has no idea that your code is asynchronous; it's up to you to copy out what you need from the event arguments if you're going to use it asynchronously.

Comment: thx for your answer. I managed to solve my Exception and indeed it was working fine using the second code. But in the end, I changed the internals to fire a trigger using a timer, instead of waiting for the ImageGrabbed event. See my Edit.